# ExactTarget SOAP API: Sending an email to SalesForce Report

Tags: marketing-cloud

I want to send an email to a Salesforce report through the SOAP API.
I need the send to be immediately and be able to track the amount of emails sent (later on)

What is the best method to do that? ET documentation describes different flows and examples, but non of them include a salesforce send.
Should I be using the List object to specify the report ID? or the EmailSendDefinition object?

FYI, I'm using [fuel-node-soap](https://github.com/ExactTarget/Fuel-Node-SOAP) to create the emails, and later on perform the sends.

Appreciate any help.

**EDIT1**
I tried using the following, but I get an error saying that I need to be integrated with Salesforce, which I am for sure (as I am able to send through the UI)

```
{ StatusCode: 'Error',
       StatusMessage: 'In order to save an audience with Salesforce data-sources in it you must be integrated with Salesforce.',
       OrdinalID: '0',
       ErrorCode: '9999999',
       NewID: '0',
       Object: [Object] }
```

Here is the request:

```
      <Body>
    <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
      <Options/>
      <Objects xsi:type="EmailSendDefinition">
        <Name>email-send-54321</Name>
        <CustomerKey>54321</CustomerKey>
        <Email>
          <ID>4512919</ID>
        </Email>
        <SendDefinitionList>
          <Name>TTTTT</Name>
          <List>
            <ID>138813</ID>
          </List>
          <SalesForceObjectID>00O0000000ABCg8</SalesForceObjectID>
          <DataSourceTypeID>SalesForceReport</DataSourceTypeID>
          <SendDefinitionListType>SourceList</SendDefinitionListType>
        </SendDefinitionList>
        <SendClassification>
          <CustomerKey>Default Transactional</CustomerKey>
        </SendClassification>
      </Objects>
    </CreateRequest>
  </Body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to configure the User Initiated Send from UI where your audience will be identified as a Salesforce Report, then simply execute that send from an API call. That should work for you without any problems.

The Salesforce sends are the configurations where your target Audience is the ET artifacts (usually data extension) and designed to allow for further segmentation.

Comment: Thank you, Vlad. The thing is - I need to create the email and the send through the API. Check out my latest edit, I was able to compile something, but it seems to give me a strange error.

Comment: Hey Nati, pretty sure that you just need to check that your API user is integrated with SF as well. Go into Email > Admin > Users > select your API user and check that under Integration option it says integrated.

Comment: Also, it's worth considering how you'll maintain all of those sends you create through API. With time if that is a frequent workflow there is a chance to accumulate too many objects on the account unless you build the housekeeping routines which delete anything after certain amount of time.